# Call to a member function result() on array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, error-handling, codeigniter-3

Controller Code:

```
$last['row']=$this->assign_model->get_last_row();
foreach($last->result() as $issue)
{
    $id=$issue->id;
    $at=$issue->time;
}
```

Model Code:

```
 public function get_last_row()
{
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM issues ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->row_array();
  return $query;
}
```

While I am executing this it will displays:

```
Message: Call to a member function result() on array
```

Can anyone help to correct this code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are fetching single row then what is the use of foreach here

```
 $last = $this->assign_model->get_last_row();
```

And simply println $last variable you can get record of last row.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this to

```
foreach($last->result() as $issue)
```

this

```
foreach($last['row'] as $issue) # or assign it with variable
```